# JSP how to store image into database from html input

Tags: java, html, jsp

I'm trying to write a code that stores images into database, then later display it on the webpage using the rollnum to retrieve it from the database. I've tried all i could but still no good, i tried reading some tutorials but still no good, anyways here's the code i'm working on. I'd be very grateful if someone could help, Thanks in Advance.

```
<%@page import="java.sql.*" %>            
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Registration Page</title>
    <style>
        body{
            background-image: url('bg.png');
            background-repeat: repeat;
            font-family: Courier New;
            margin:auto;
            width: 1000px;
        }            
        .wrap{
        margin-top:10px;
        border:solid 1px #000;
        height:900px;            
        }
        .header{
            font-size: 50px;
            font-weight: bold;
            font-family: Courier New; 
            text-align: center;

        }
        .border{
            border-bottom: solid 1px #000;
            margin-left: 30px;
            margin-right: 30px;
        }
        .box{
            border: solid 1px #000;
            padding: 8px;
            margin: 30px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrap">
        <table>
            <form method="post">
                <br/>                                  
                <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;Roll Number:</td> <td><input type="text" name="rollnum"/></td>
                </tr>
                </div>
                <tr>
                    <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;First Name:</td> <td><input type="text" name="fname"/></td>
                </tr>                     
                <tr>
                    <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;Last Name:</td> <td><input type="text" name="lname"/></td>
                </tr>                                         
                <tr>
                    <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;Course Name:</td> <td><input type="text" name="course"/></td>
                </tr>                                         
                <tr>
                    <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;Gender:</td> <td>Male:<input type="radio" name="gender" value="Male"/> Female:<input type="radio" name="gender" value="Female"/></td>
                </tr>                                         
                <tr>
                    <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;Address:</td> <td><input type="text" name="addr"/></td>
                </tr>                                                             
                <tr>
                    <td>&nbsp;&nbsp; State:</td> <td><input type="text" name="state"/></td>
                </tr>                                         
                <tr>
                    <td>&nbsp;&nbsp; Photo:<input type="file" name="photo"/></td>
                </tr>                                                             
                <tr>
                    <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit"/></td>
                </tr>                                                             

            </form>
        </table>                        
        <%
            try{
            if(request.getParameter("submit") != null){
            Connection conn;
            PreparedStatement prep;    
            String sql;
            String url = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/reg";                                        
            Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver");                
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,"uname","pass");                


            sql = 
                "insert into student (rollnum,fname,lname,course,gender,addr,state,photo)"
                +"values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";                                

            ResultSet rs = null;

            prep = conn.prepareStatement(sql);

            prep.setInt(1, Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("rollnum")));
            prep.setString(2, request.getParameter("fname"));
            prep.setString(3, request.getParameter("lname"));
            prep.setString(4, request.getParameter("course"));
            prep.setString(5, request.getParameter("gender"));
            prep.setString(6, request.getParameter("addr"));
            prep.setString(7, request.getParameter("state"));                
            //prep.setString(8, request.getParameter("photo"));
            Blob blob = rs.getBlob(request.getParameter("photo"));;
            prep.setBlob(8, blob);                
            int n = prep.executeUpdate();
            if(n>0){                                    
        %>
        <div class="box">Registration Successful!! <b><a href="login.jsp">Login Now!!</a></b></div>
        <%
            }   
            }
            }

            catch(ClassNotFoundException e){

            }
            catch(NumberFormatException n){

            }
        %>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: To help the community better answer your question, please describe what your expectation is, how your are testing and provide the errors you are seeing, if any.

Comment: Here's how basically all experimentations work: you try something, you observe what happens, then you try to change things until what you observe is what you want to achieve. The corollary is that if you don't know what you want to achieve, and if you don't observe anything, you can't progress. Since you didn't say anything about what you wanted to achieve, and anything about what you're observing, we can't help. I'm always astonished that half of the newbies here don't understand this basic principle.

Comment: @JBNizet i've edited the question, could you help now please

Comment: And you still haven't told anything about your observations. What **precisely** happens? Saying "it doesn't work" doesn't help at all.

Comment: @JBNizet, it doesn't work at all

Comment: OK. If that's the best you can do after so many explanations on what you should provide, I'll vote to close. I wouldn't like to be your doctor: You: "doctor, it hurts, please help". Doctor: "where does it hurts? when? for how long?" You: "it hurts badly". Doctor: "Aaaaaarg!"

Comment: Can you see the weg page? Is there any error? What exactly happens?

Comment: it's giving a Nullpointer Exception.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this way:

- Get the image
- Convert the image with the base64 rappresentation
- Store the base64 into your db
- when you need the image convert again the base64 into the image